# I2C output error when sending an array

Tags: arrays, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have recently started using Node-RED in a Raspberry Pi and my quest is to connect to a couple of I2C devices with the use of the node-red-contrib-i2c package. 
One action which I am trying to do is to send an array of integers to the I2C device with the I2C output node but I always get the error

`TypeError: String.isString is not a function`

I have tried a couple of different syntax but without success. I have included an export of the flow below.

```
[{"id":"d2a2b073.e222c","type":"function","z":"e442e95f.6c2b98","name":"","func":"msg.address = 96;\nmsg.command = 48;\nmsg.payload = [85,85];\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":316,"y":243,"wires":[["7061e7e7.ac6f98","65101109.cf323"]]},{"id":"ce6f4bff.3bf998","type":"inject","z":"e442e95f.6c2b98","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":126,"y":244,"wires":[["d2a2b073.e222c"]]},{"id":"7061e7e7.ac6f98","type":"debug","z":"e442e95f.6c2b98","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":539,"y":263,"wires":[]},{"id":"65101109.cf323","type":"i2c out","z":"e442e95f.6c2b98","name":"","i2cdevice":"3d751c57.1120f4","address":"96","command":"","payload":"","count":"2","x":567,"y":223,"wires":[]},{"id":"3d751c57.1120f4","type":"i2c-device","z":"","device":"/dev/i2c-1","address":"100"}]
```

An example of the msg.payload sent:

```
msg.address = 96;
msg.command = 48;
msg.payload = [85,85];
return msg;
```

Comment: Presumably the error is in the i2c-out node? Edit your question - please add an example of msg.payload that gives this error.

Comment: I updated the question with an example of the msg.payload and made a small update of the flow

Comment: Have you tried converting the object payload to a JSON string payload before sending into the i2c out node?

Comment: I added a JSON node before the I2C OUT node but I still get the same error as before.

Comment: Sounds like a proble in the node.

Comment: There are other nodes that can do i2c, for example node-red-contrib-gpio, but you might want to remove the node-red-contrib-i2c before trying that - I had an unpleasant experience once when a bluetooth node I had installed but wasn't using still loaded some bluetooth stuff that conflicted with something else I was trying IYSWIM.

Comment: Ok thx, I will test out both the node-red-contrib-gpio package and also try a workaround using the EXEC node and calling I2CSET